# how to solve #error : Must define a target architecture in wince mfc application?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, windows-ce

how to solve #error : Must define a target architecture in wince mfc application?i got to know that we need to use device header and libraries but how can i use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the error is because you're trying to build the application against the (desktop) Windows SDK. The easiest thing to do is to create a new "Win32 Smart Device" project and add your code to it.

Alternatively, check the "Compile for architecture" setting under project properties -> C/C++ and ensure that it is set for the appropriate architecture.

Comment: Amazing, another accepted answer that isn't "useful". @Suri: I notice you've asked 63 questions but only given 20 upvotes. Seems like an odd ratio to me. Especially since you've accepted nearly 30 answers. I'm glad I was able to help solve your problem, but please take advantage of the mechanisms that are in place on this site.

Comment: There Cody, I did it for him :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to globally define some macro like `_X86_` in the project options, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You'll also need to define `_M_IX86` to get past that warning, but there will be other problems after that.