# compilation error - Must define a target architecture

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, architecture, compilation

I have a project that worked with windows vista and now I'm trying to compile the project on win 7. I'm getting compilation error :  Must define a target architecture.

I looked for this error and I found that I need to change the "Compile for Architecture" in advanced  Project Properties. 
The problem is that I can't find this option. I'm working with visual studio 2008.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677195/how-to-solve-error-must-define-a-target-architecture-in-wince-mfc-application

Comment: yes, I read it, and as I said I can't find the "Compile for architecture" option, but thanks anyway

Comment: What do you find @ Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced ??

Comment: I don't see Compile for architecture. I see Entry Point, No Entry Point, Set Checksum, Base Address and so on.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ has the following structure for compiling:

```
///// Preproccessors ///// >  Object Files ///// >> Link with together and libraries //// >> executable file.
```

When you change arch, You should `rebuild all`

Comment: OK, thank you, but the problem is that I can't find where to change the arch.. can you help?

Comment: Unfortunately or fortunately i just work under UNIX world.I think at first you need to a virtualization...